# Hidden Backup HDD

Tags: windows, backup

I have a spare HDD in my computer which I use Backup and Restore in Windows Control Panel to backup to automatically. I only want this hard drive for this one feature. How can I hide the Hard Drive so no one can write files to it (We all share an Administrator account as a family). I couldn't find a solution to my problem using the search feature so if it has been asked before please point me to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could hide the drive letter in my computer. This would stop people seeing it. This may be enough. [This](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/hide-drives-from-your-computer-in-windows-vista/) guide shows you how to do it in Vista / Windows 7
If not then you could also then set permissions on the drive to be system only (If this is the account Windows backup uses). You could take ownership of the files again as administrator when you needed it.

Comment: @Sam - Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on Computer (or My Computer, depending on the Windows version) and select **Manage** then select **Disk Management**. From here you can remove the drive letter associated with that disk, effectively hiding it. To get it back, just assign a drive letter again.

Comment: Will windows backup still work for this though? I removed the drive letter before I started the backup and it was not recognized as a valid backup location.

Comment: @Sam: As the answer says, "To get it back, just assign a drive letter again."

Comment: To make this work you'd have to enable it every time you ran Windows backup and then disable it when it had finished. A scheduled task could be set to do this. It's messy but it would in theory work

Answer (score 1):

Its a little tricky, but presumably you could mount the partition as a [folder](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889), set that as a hidden folder and backup to that.

*Not* using the admin account on as your usual account is a good idea, but unrelated to the answer.